# How to give attribute value dynamically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden field as given below.

```
<input type="hidden" value="home" name="newdirpath" />
<input type="button" id="btn"/>
```

How can i give a value to the attribute `value` dynamically through jquery ?

My Jquery is something like this.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text="helloworld"
    /* What shall I given here for inputting the value of variable text into the attribute `value` of input tag */
});
```

Please advice me as I am beginner in Jquery and html.Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll find the documentation very helpful for some of these questions: http://api.jquery.com/ They have a useful search tool.

Comment: Please do some research before posting questions here.

Comment: One more [learn jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text="helloworld"
    $('input[name="newdirpath"]').attr("value",text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text="helloworld";
    $("input[name=newdirpath]").val(text);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QHGyE/

Answer (score 0):

give your hidden input an id like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="home" name="newdirpath" id="newdirpath" />
```

and then your jquery becomes like this:

```
$('#newdirpath').val("your value goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text= "helloworld";
    $('input[name="newdirpath"]').val(text);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TAy5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too...

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text= "helloworld";
    $(this).prev().attr('value',text);
});
```

If you want to be more specific because you have multiple hidden input fields before it and you simply want to target one, then you could optionally look up a hidden field by its name attribute like this...

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var text= "helloworld";
    $(this).prev('input[name=newdirpath]').attr('value',text);
});
```

View my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/vkrbE/4/) and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<input type="hidden" id="ids" value="home" name="newdirpath" />
```

and

```
$('#ids').val(text);
```

Comment: @wumm yup.Thanks for the spot :)